# Why I can't open a BootStrap modal performing also a jQuery callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am pretty new in JQuery and BootStrap and I have the following problem.

I have this BootStrap modal:

```
<div id="variazioneAnticipoModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" style="color: #3b5a76;">Variazione Anticipo</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body">       
        <div id="inserimentoVariazioneAnticipo">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <p style="line-height: 200%;">Inserire la variazione dell'anticipo: </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <input id="variazioneAnticipo" class="rightAlligned form-control" style="width:50%" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="variazioneAnticpoInvalida" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none; margin-top: 3%;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                            Il valore inserito non &egrave; valido
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Hidden by default: -->
        <div id="confermaVariazioneAnticipo" style="display: none;">
          <h3>Confermare variazione anticipo ?</h3>
        </div>          
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="chiudiVariaAnticipoButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        <button id="variaAnticipoButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Varia anticipo</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Then I have this JQuery script that open the modal and that set a div that have to be shown and a div that have to be hidden when the modal is opened:

```
$('#variazioneAnticipoModal').modal('show'); 
$("#inserimentoVariazioneAnticipo").show();
$("#confermaVariazioneAnticipo").hide();
```

This works fine.

The problem is that I have tryied to restructure this simple JQuery code using the **callback function** concept.

So I have tried to do:

```
$('#variazioneAnticipoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#inserimentoVariazioneAnticipo").show();
  $("#confermaVariazioneAnticipo").hide();  
});
```

but it can't work and the modal is not shown.

I also tryied to insert only an alert message in the callback function to debug purpose but still can't work. The alert popup is not shown and the modal is not opened.

Why? What am I missing? Is it better use the callback concept in this case or I can use the first working code? What is the difference from my first working example and the use of callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to init the modal first.

Try to put: `$('#variazioneAnticipoModal').modal();`
before your code, like this:

```
 $('#variazioneAnticipoModal').modal();
 $('#variazioneAnticipoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#inserimentoVariazioneAnticipo").show();
        $("#confermaVariazioneAnticipo").hide();

    });
```

show.bs.modal works while model dialog loading, shown.bs.modal worked to do any thing after loading. post rendering.
But you need to init the modal first so that it will have those events.

Comment: Ok it works but what exactly is the difference from the first code (the one that do not use the callback function) and the second one that use callback? From what I have understand the use of the callback ensure that the code inside the callback definition is performed after that the modal is opened. Is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: The first code initializes the dialog: $('#variazioneAnticipoModal').modal('show');

Comment: According to Bootstrap documentation: `.show.bs.modal`: This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the relatedTarget property of the event.

Comment: No I am refering to: why use callback in this case? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: If not initialize the modal by doing .modal() or .modal('show') the dialog actually will not have events that you want to subscribe to - of the events is .show.bs.modal

Comment: both are ok to use. I think the second one is more appropriate because you catch the event of the show and do something with it.

Comment: You have to use callback function because you want to hide and show divs during an action (modal opening). You can not achieve that without callback function. The essence of callback functions is that you can pass function as a parameter.